# open and closed set in $\mathbb{(L_1(\mathbb{R^n})}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

In a test I had was written if $X=(f\in\mathbb{L_1}\mathbb{R^n}|m(f^{-1}((0,\infty))=0)$ is open or closed in $\mathbb{(L_1(\mathbb{R^n})}$.
I suspect that this set is none  but I am not sure. Is that true? Can you please help me?

Comment: It seems closed. Try to figure out what the condition describing the set means.

Comment: Suppose $f\in X$ and $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$ in $L_1$. Passing thought a subsequence so that $f_{n_k}$ assume w.l.o.g that $f_n$ converges to $f$ $m$-a.s. $\{f>0\}=\bigcup_n\bigcap_{m\geq n}\{f_n>0\}$ almost surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $f\in X$ means that $f(x)\le 0$ (a.e.). In order to show that $X$ is closed, assume $f_n\in X$ and  $\|f_n-f\|_1\to 0.$ We have to show that $f(x)\le 0$ a.e., i.e. $f\in X.$ Although it seems obvious, the proof is given below.  We will base on the inequality $$|\min(a,0)-\min(b,0)|\le |a-b|\qquad (*)$$
As $f_n\in X,$ then $f_n(x)=\min(f_n(x),0).$ Denote $g(x)=\min(f(x),0).$ By $(*)$ we get
$$\|f_n-f\|_1=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\,dx\ge \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_n(x)-g(x)|\,dx=\|f_n-g\|_1$$
We obtain $f_n\to g$ in $L^1.$ Therefore $f=g\le 0, $ i.e. $f\in X.$

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment and answer. I was reading your solution and it sounds perfect. this question was written for a test in my university and the correct answer according to my professor was"not open and not closed" and that confused me. Do you know if online there are some similar exercise to this ? L1 function , closed and open set in L1, especially this last. Thanks again

Comment: @JoshuaC I didn't come across such exercises before. Perhaps you can look up textbooks covering measure theory. You have confused me by the opinion  of your professor. Did he provide any explanation ?

Comment: any explanation unfortunately , it was an old test .I don't know maybe there was a printing error , or I don't know. I will talk to him .Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is indeed a closed subset in $L_1$. To wit, Let $f\in \overline{X}$ and $(f_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset X $ such that $\|f-f_n\|_1\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. There is a subsequence $n_k$ such that $f_{n_k}(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ for $m$ -almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. Without lose of generality assume $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$ pointwise $m$-almost surely. That is, $M=\{x:f_n(x)\not\rightarrow f(x)\}$ has $m(M)=0$.
Then
$$\{x:\in M^c:f(x)>0\}\subset\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}\{x\in M^c: f_k(x)>0\}$$
Consequently
\begin{align}
m(f>0)&=m(M^c\cap\{f>0\})\leq m\Big(\bigcup_n\bigcap_{k\geq n}M^c\cap\{f_k>0\}\Big)\\
&=\lim_n m\Big(\bigcap_{k\geq n}M^c\cap\{f_k>0\}\Big)\leq\liminf_k m(M^c\cap\{f_k>0\})=0
\end{align}
That is $f\in X$.